# Using Python basemap etopo() generates IndexError

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to basemap working. I've installed matplotlib, basemap, and Pillow successfully and can plot basic plots. The code below works for me.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection = 'mill',
        llcrnrlat = -90,
        llcrnrlon = -180,
        urcrnrlat = 90,
        urcrnrlon = 180,
        resolution = 'c')

m.drawcoastlines()
#m.etopo()

plt.show()
```

However, uncommenting the 'etopo()' command yields the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\helper.py", line 13, in <module> m.etopo()

  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py",    line 4061, in etopo return self.warpimage(image='etopo',scale=scale,**kwargs)

  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 4167, in warpimage np.concatenate((self._bm_lons,self._bm_lons+360),1)

IndexError: axis 1 out of bounds [0, 1)
```

I've tried reinstalling and updating all relevant packages, but that hasn't worked. I also can't find anything on this error for this situation. I'm on Windows 8.1 with 32 bit Python 3.5.1

Comment: I was able to make this code work on a different computer running 64 bit Python 3.5.1 (also Windows 8.1). Is it possible 32 bit vs. 64 bit has something to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just testing `Basemap` and `.etopo()` functionality, I updated your script:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make a miller cylindrical projection with defaults
m = Basemap('mill')

m.drawcoastlines()
# now displays topo relief image
m.etopo()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. I am still a bit confused though. My original code is actually from a basemap tutorial (paid Udemy course, so I can't provide the link unfortunately) and it ran perfectly in the tutorial. I actually was able to get my original code to work on a different comp running 64 bit Python.

Comment: Sure thing @DataBandit. I made a large edit because after more testing on my setup, miller projection with the defaults works fine with `.etopo()`. One thing to compare on each of the different machines is: inside your python interpreter, enter `import mpl_toolkits.basemap` and then `print mpl_toolkits.basemap.__version__` and see if they're different versions. FYI I'm on a mac with 64-bit python 2.7 and your code gives the same error on my machine.

Comment: The basemap version of the comp throwing the error is 1.0.8. Don't have access to the other comp at the moment. Something interesting about what you posted: it runs, but if I change `m = Basemap('mill')` to `m = Basemap(projection = 'mill')`, it fails! With the same error as above.

Comment: Yep - miller projection with any custom args doesn't work with `.etopo()`, while the default `mill` works. Interestingly, the simplest cylinder projection, `m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,\
            llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,resolution='c')` (from http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/cyl.html) works fine with custom args and `.etopo()`. If you check out the full list at http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapsetup.html, I haven't tested them all, but many projections with args seem to work with `.etopo()`. Miller's "cousin" Mercator, also gives the same error.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an incompatibilty between basemap and recent numpy versions. The suggested solution reverts to the default projection, since the first keyword is not projection but llcrnrlat.

I haven't figures out what exactly causes the IndexError, however reverting to an older numpy version works. It seems numpy 1.9.2 is the latest working version. It might be that something was changed with the concatenate command.

Edit:
I changed line 4167 in basemap/**init**.py to obtain the same result than it must have been with older numpy versions. It seems to do the trick:

```
Old: np.concatenate((self._bm_lons,self._bm_lons+360),1)
New: np.concatenate((self._bm_lons.T,self._bm_lons.T+360)).T
```

Concatenating along 1D arrays and a non zero axis, is now deprecated, which is why the exception is raised.